# XML::LibXML::Reader return value without cdata tag

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I am reading an xml file with XML::LibXML::Reader

```
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => $fh, load_ext_dtd => 0) or die qq(cannot read content: $!);

while ($reader->nextElement( 'item' )) {

    my $copy = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);

    my $title = $copy->findvalue( 'title' );  

}
```

However, the title in the xml is inside a CDATA tag, so if I look at it, it is like

```
<![CDATA[Some title here]]>
```

I could naturally use some regex to get rid of the extra tags, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way for XML::LibXML::reader to return the title without the cdata tags ?

I've been looking through the docs, but can't find any reference to a way to do that.

Comment: By the way, there are two errors in your first line. 1) `->new` is not a system call, so `$!` is meaningless on error.  2) `->new` doesn't return undef on error; it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks ikegami I will correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the parser's job to decode the XML for you, so `findvalue` already returns what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML::Reader qw( );

my $xml = '<root><item><title><![CDATA[Some title here]]></title></item></root>';

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(string => $xml, load_ext_dtd => 0);
while ($reader->nextElement( 'item' )) {
    my $copy = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    my $title = $copy->findvalue( 'title' );
    say $title;       # Some title here
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, there was a typo on their cdata tag I had missed. Thanks